# How do I get pretty xhtml format in Netbeans IDE 12?

Tags: xml, netbeans, xhtml, netbeans-plugins

I'm editing xhtml files in Netbeans IDE 12.0. The files are from LibreOffice Writer export to EPUB 3. The first time I opened one of these files, it had two lines. In the sample below, I only copied part of the second line because all the rest of the file was on that one line, with no newline at the end.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><link href="../styles/stylesheet.css" rel="styl ...
```

That first time I opened the file, I chose to manually insert newlines at the end of tags. As soon as I hit the return key once, Netbeans formatted the entire file. Since then, I have not been able to repeat that trick. I have tried the menu item Source, Format. I installed the XML Quick Format plugin, but I can't figure out how to use it; it came with no instructions.

Any idea how to reformat these files with nice xhtml indenting?